# Is it possible to specify the "this" in jQuery Deferred callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

Is it possible to specify the "this" in jQuery Deferred callbacks?
(like in Array.prototype.map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery's `$.proxy()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
$.get( "test.php" ).then( 
    $.proxy(this.good,this), 
    $.proxy(this.fail,this)
);
```

or [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
$.get( "test.php" ).then( 
    this.good.bind(this), 
    this.fail.bind(this)
);
```

Comment: Additonally in the case when you control the deferred object, you can call deferred.resolveWith(thisArg)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use native javascript to bind the 'this' to the function passed.

Something like:

```
$.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.then( function(response) {
   console.log(this);
}.bind(this))
```

I have made a fiddle with this example
https://jsfiddle.net/8xk0s4na/